# Unable to get this to loop. Need this to go line by line

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
ftplist = open('C:\Documents and Settings\jasong\My Documents\GooleDrive\lookup.txt','r')
txt = ftplist.read()

re1='([a-z]:\\\\(?:[-\\w\\.\\d]+\\\\)*(?:[-\\w\\.\\d]+)?)'

rg = re.compile(re1,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    winpath1=m.group(1)
    print "("+winpath1+")"+"\n"
```

Comment: What does this code do? Where is the loop?

Comment: Well, it doesn't loop because there's no loop in it. What are you trying to do and what is happening instead of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Loop directly over the file object:

```
with open(r'C:\Documents and Settings\jasong\My Documents\GooleDrive\lookup.txt','r') as ftplist:
    for line in ftplist:
        match = rg.search(line)
```

This will read the file efficiently, without having to load everything into memory first.

Note: I also made your path a raw string (by adding `r` in front of it) to prevent Python from trying to interpret escape sequences starting with a `\` backslash; `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and `\b` all have special meaning in a normal string. It is generally a good idea to use raw strings for Windows file paths, although you can also use forward slashes or double backslash characters as well.

Comment: Or maybe the OP can get away with a `re.findall()` with the code they've already got... Although, it does look like they're trying to do something with a list of mapped network drives on Windows... (curious to know if that file is the output of `net use` or something)

Comment: the text file holds a list of all the directory's on an ftp server.  I'm looking for the script to parse out the rest of the data and just give me the directory name.  I tried using re.findall() but it creates a list and I'm having a hard time using RE against that list.

Comment: I think it is important that it is explicitly pointed out to the OP that you have added the `r` in front of the string in `with open(r'C:\Documents...`.  This makes a raw string and will prevent things like `\t` or `\n` from being interpreted as a special character.

Comment: @user2905001: Why now loop over that list then? Each entry is a match.

Comment: Martijin, I do not understand your implementation but I would like to use it.  Not quite sure what I'm supposed to replace.  Where is the regex supposed to go?

with open(r'C:\Documents and Settings\jasong\My Documents\GooleDrive\lookup.txt','r') as ftplist:
    for line in ftplist:
        match = rg.search(line)

Comment: @user2905001: This is the main body of code; put the things that don't change outside of the loop, so define the compiled regex before either the `with` statement or the `for` loop, doesn't really matter that much where.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you give me a hand.  I still don't understand where to put your with 
`
import re
ftplist = open('C:\Documents and Settings\jasong\My Documents\GooleDrive\lookup.txt','r')
txt = ftplist.read()

re1='([a-z]:\\\\(?:[-\\w\\.\\d]+\\\\)*(?:[-\\w\\.\\d]+)?)'

rg = re.findall(re1,txt)
#m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    winpath1=m.group(1)
    print "("+winpath1+")"+"\n"
`